# helm ignores set values while deploying mongodb

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to deploy mongodb with a service of type NodePort using helm by executing either

```
helm install --name rocky stable/mongodb -f mongodb_values.yaml
```

or

```
helm install --set service.type=NodePort,service.nodePort=30099 --name rocky stable/mongodb
```

However both commands seem to ignore my changes to the default values and I end up with a service of type ClusterIP. Any ideas?

Comment: Works like a charm. What helm version do you use?

Comment: Works for me too. Perhaps do `helm repo update` in case you are getting an old version of the chart. Can also help to add `--dry-run --debug` and inspect the output and be sure that it evaluates to what you think it does.

Comment: Problem solved by updating helm repositories.